# How can i give form and field validation to my fields?

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, django-validation

I want to add some validation if user try to register or login he must go through some restrictions. Please help me someone as i am new to django 
models.py

```
class RegisterData(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    GENDER_CHOICE =(
        ('Male','Male'),
        ('Female', 'Female')
    )
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=GENDER_CHOICE)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    password1 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    password2 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=40)
    mobile = models.BigIntegerField()
    dob = models.DateField()
```

forms.py

I used to write forms like this instead of modelforms. If someone try to register then he must obey some rules that like password characters and length, username should be right like that.

registration form

```
class RegisterForm(forms.Form):
first_name =  forms.CharField(
    label='First name ',
    widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            'class':'form-control',
            'placeholder':'Enter your first name'
        }
    )
)

last_name = forms.CharField(
    label='Last name ',
    widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'Enter your last name'
        }
    )
)

GENDER_CHOICE = (
    ('male', 'Male'),
    ('female', 'Female')
)

gender = forms.ChoiceField(
    widget=forms.RadioSelect(),
    choices=GENDER_CHOICE
)

username = forms.CharField(
    label='User name ',
    widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            'class':'form-control',
            'placeholder':'Enter your user name'
        }
    )
)
password1 = forms.CharField(
    label='Password ',
    widget=forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs={
            'class':'form-control',
            'placeholder':'Enter your password'
        }
    )
)
password2 = forms.CharField(
    label='Password',
    widget=forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs={
            'class':'form-control',
            'placeholder':'Re-enter your password'
        }
    )
)

email = forms.EmailField(
    label='Email-id',
    widget=forms.EmailInput(
        attrs={
            'class':'form-control',
            'placeholder':'Enter your email id'
        }
    )
)
mobile = forms.IntegerField(
    label='Mobile ',
    widget=forms.NumberInput(
        attrs={
            'class':'form-control',
            'placeholder':'Enter your mobile number'
        }
    )
)
dob = forms.CharField(
    label='DOB ',
    widget=forms.DateInput(
        attrs={
            'class':'form-control',
            'placeholder':'Enter your date of birth'
        }
    )
)
```

loginform

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(
        label='User name ',
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Enter your user name'
            }
        )
    )
    password1 = forms.CharField(
        label='Password ',
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(
            attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Enter your password'
            }
        )
    )
```

views.py

```
def regview(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    rform = RegisterForm(request.POST)
    if rform.is_valid():
        first_name = request.POST.get('first_name','')
        last_name = request.POST.get('last_name', '')
        gender = rform.cleaned_data.get('gender', '')
        username = request.POST.get('username', '')
        password1 = request.POST.get('password1', '')
        password2 = request.POST.get('password2', '')
        email = request.POST.get('email', '')
        mobile = request.POST.get('mobile', '')
        dob = rform.cleaned_data.get('dob', '')

        data = RegisterData(
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
            gender=gender,
            username=username,
            password1=password1,
            password2=password2,
            email=email,
            mobile=mobile,
            dob=dob
        )
        data.save()
        rform = RegisterForm()
        lform = LoginForm()
        return render(request, 'reg.html', {'rform':rform, 'lform': lform})

    if request.method == 'POST':
        lform = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if lform.is_valid():
            username = request.POST.get('username','')
            password1 = request.POST.get('password1','')
            user = RegisterData.objects.filter(username=username)
            pwd = RegisterData.objects.filter(password1=password1)

            if user and pwd:
                return redirect('/ask')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid credentials')
    # lform = LoginForm()
    # return render(request,'reg.html',{'lform':lform})
else:
    rform = RegisterForm()
    lform = LoginForm()
    return render(request,'reg.html',{'rform':rform ,'lform':lform})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# you can use clean function in your forms.py class

For Example

def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    username = cleaned_data.get("username")
    password = cleaned_data.get("password")

    if len(username)<=8:
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            "Username field length should be more than 8 characters"
        )

    return cleaned_data
```

Comment: In django default authentication is there i want something like that

Comment: Django normal form field does support this `forms.CharField(min_length=6)` [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/validators/#minlengthvalidator)

Answer (score 0):

Another options if you want to use default user form from Django [password validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/passwords/#password-validation):

```
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'min_length': 8,
        }
    },
]
```

Comment: I want something like @decorators function which will the register and login credentials automatically...I didn't understand the documentation it is there